# INSTALL NS 2.34 ON UBUNTU 12.04

Tags: 12.04

i have been trying to install ns 2.34 onto ubuntu 12.04 but it shows error while running command for gcc 4.3 version.it shows package not found. so which version of gcc is to be installed for installing ns 2.34 onto ubuntu 12.04

Comment: The version most appropriate for Ubuntu 12.04 is 2.35. Do you want 2.34 to install?

Answer (score 0):

The NS2 network simulator is in the Universe repository, so you don't have to compile it yourself. Make sure you have the universe repository enabled, then look for the "ns2" package in the software center.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ns2